# e-mail azw to Kindle Personal Documents Service?

Tags: kindle, epub, conversion, send-to-kindle, azw

To convert `epub` to the `azw` [format](https://www.epubconverter.com/epub-to-azw-converter/) I've tried an [online conversion tool](https://www.epubconverter.com/epub-to-azw-converter/) and then sending the generated file to myself as an attachment.

So far this doesn't *seem* work so well.

Yet sending `mobi` files from this site *seems* to work perfectly.

I've installed `calibre` but have yet to fully test exporting or converting locally.  Also, it might be that Amazon doesn't "like" the generated `azw` files as I got a cryptic message:

> The following document, sent at 02:56 AM on Wed, Mar 21, 2018 PDT
>   could not be delivered to the Kindle you specified:
>   * 1 - Dune - Frank Herbert (1965).azw3
>
> The Kindle Personal Document Service can convert and deliver the
>   following types of documents: Microsoft Word (.doc, .docx) Rich Text
>   Format (.rtf) HTML (.htm, .html) Text (.txt) documents Archived
>   documents (zip , x-zip) and compressed archived documents Mobi book

yet when I check the documentation online:

Kindle Personal Documents Service supports the following file types:

Kindle Format (.MOBI, .AZW)
Microsoft Word (.DOC, .DOCX)
HTML (.HTML, .HTM)
RTF (.RTF)
Text (.TXT)
JPEG (.JPEG, .JPG)
GIF (.GIF)
PNG (.PNG)
BMP (.BMP)
PDF (.PDF)

There's `azw` plain as day.

Yes, I should be able to load the `azw` file, either generated locally or through the web service.  Curious about the gotcha's here, or others experience with the "send to Kindle" service.

Comment: The file you sent seems to have "azw3" as its file extension. Have you tried renaming the file to just "azw" before sending it?

Comment: @Hazzit no, I'll have to try a few other things from `Calibre`.