# bulk conversion of EPUB for Kindle (mobi)

Tags: kindle, mobi, send-to-kindle, kindle-cloud-reader, azw

While I've never had [success](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/7719/9853) with converting `epub` to `azw` or `azw3`, converting to `mobi` works fine for me.  For a large number of `epub` files what's a good workflow or tool for converting to a `Kindle` friendly format?

*Every file is `epub`, which "send to Kindle" won't accept.  None of the files are `PDF`, nor is `PDF` desired as an output.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Calibre You can select several books at once, and hit convert. It is an old feature, described on the [official blog](http://blog.calibre-ebook.com/2011/10/ebook-fomat-conversion.html):

> Bulk convert: Calibre allows you to convert books in bulk. You can
>   select a set of books, all of which may or may not be in the same
>   format, and convert them all in bulk to a different format. So say you
>   have a kindle and you have a number of books in EPUB, RTF and PDF
>   formats. You can select them all. Then click the "Convert books" icon
>   or click the little arrow next to the "Convert books" icon and choose
>   the option "Bulk convert". A new window  opens. At the top right
>   corner of the window you can set the output format, which in this case
>   would be MOBI.

If You are on Linux, You can also write a script to utilize Calibre's command line capabilities.